# Save NSString from CFStringRef. ARC

Tags: ios6, abaddressbook, core-foundation

I'm trying to save `firstName` and `lastname`.
`NSLog(firstName);` prints correct value from addressbook, but `_dossier.firstName` is empty.
Image is saving correctly.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();

for (TKAddressBook *ab in contacts) {
    NSNumber *personID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:ab.recordID];
    ABRecordID abRecordID = (ABRecordID)[personID intValue];
    ABRecordRef abPerson = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(addressBook, abRecordID);

    NSString* firstName = nil;
    NSString* lastName = nil;


    // Check person image
    UIImage *personImage = nil;
    if (abPerson != nil && ABPersonHasImageData(abPerson)) {

        firstName = (__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(abPerson,
                                                          kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        NSLog(firstName);
        lastName = (__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(abPerson,
                                                         kABPersonLastNameProperty);

        CFDataRef contactThumbnailData = ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(abPerson, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail);
        personImage = [UIImage imageWithData:(__bridge NSData*)contactThumbnailData];
        CFRelease(contactThumbnailData);
        [_document.managedObjectContext performBlock:^() {
            Dossier *dossier = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Dossier"
                                                             inManagedObjectContext:_document.managedObjectContext];

            _dossier.firstName = firstName;
            _dossier.lastName = lastName;

            dossier.photo = personImage;
        }];

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `_dossier` ? Shouldn't it be `dossier.firstName = firstName; dossier.lastName = lastName;` ?

Comment: _dossier is UIManagedDocument

Comment: I don't think this will help with the problem, but you should be using `__bridge_transfer` (or `CFBridgingRelease`) on the return values from `ABRecordCopyValue`.

Comment: What happens if you `NSLog(@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName)` within the block?

Comment: So you want to save `personImage` in the newly created `Dossier *dossier` object, but `firstName` and `lastName` in the `UIManagedDocument *_dossier` (which is a different object) ?

Comment: Another point: `performBlock:` might execute *asynchronously* if the managed object context is of the private concurrency type. You can try if using `performBlockAndWait:` solves your problem.

Comment: @MartinR Oh! Such a stupid mistake I made :) Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Which one was it? `dossier` vs. `_dossier`? I would like to add it as a formal answer, which you can "accept".

Comment: Yes @MartinR , exactly. Please do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `performBlock` you have assigned `firstName` and `lastName` to `_dossier` instead of the newly created `dossier` object.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
firstName = (__bridge NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(abPerson,
        NSLog(firstName);                                                              kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

Your `NSLog` interrupts the statement. Unless the formatting somehow messed up really bad.